# How to transform a set of negative values to obtain a normal distribution?

Tags: p-value, data-transformation, normalization, shapiro-wilk-test

I am having quite a few problems with transforming a set of data with values between -1 and 0, as I need to normalise them.

I tried to use the following formulae:

[(−min())/(max()−min())]

AND

atahn[(−min())/(max()−min())]

But both don't seem to work... As the p-value is always below 0.05 using the Shapiro-Wilk test.

Can I transform the data using the log[(−min())/(max()−min())] formula? Is this appropriate? Thanks xx

CLARIFICATION: Sorry guys, I am quite new to these things, I thought "normalise" meant making sure that a set of data was normally distributed.
I have a set of data and I have to check to see whether they are normally distributed - and to see that, I was told that I have to use the Shapiro-Wilk test, which must be above 0.05, a histogram, and a Q-Q graph (I am using SPSS). But the data that I have comprises all negative values, and when I checked they were not normally distributed. On the Internet, I read that I have to log-transform my data, but since they're all negative values, I tried the two options above in my original post - plus log(x+1) yesterday evening. But nothing seems to work. My question was whether I could use the following formula log[(−min())/(max()−min()) to transform my data and achieve normal distribution? Because I can't find anything else on the Internet on that... Or if there was anything else I could try?

Comment: Please explain how normalization produces a p-value.  It seems like you might be trying to do something very different from what you are asking about.

Comment: “Normalization” does not produce normal distributions. Normalization produces values in the interval $[0,1]$. For what reason do you need to “normalize” your data?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that "normalize" and achieve "normal distribution" were two different things. I edited the post - hopefully it's makes sense now.

Comment: What do you mean when you ask if you can do it? You did the transformation, right? So you *can* do it. If you’re asking if you *should* do it, assess the results. Do the transformed data look normal? It might help to say more about what you’re doing, particularly why you want a normal distribution at all.

Comment: I need a normal distribution because after that I am required to do an ANOVA. I just tried using the formula log[(−min())/(max()−min()) and it does look like a normal distribution now. But I'm not sure whether that's an appropriate way or if I'm just making up the results, because I couldn't find anything on the Internet regarding this method...

Comment: Please ask about the actual statistical problem you have.  Your current question is not going to solve it--it will instead lead you astray.  ANOVA does not require normality.  When you apply a nonlinear transformation you are changing what ANOVA does, anyway: it no longer compares arithmetic means of groups.  If you really, really, want to transform anyway, then simply negate all your values and watch for answers to [the same question about values between $0$ and $1.$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/570907)

Comment: This [site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ANOVA+transform+normal*+score%3A1) turns up many relevant posts.