# What is a good type of transformation to try on this data to get normal distribution?

Tags: r, python, dataset, descriptive-statistics

[image]

I've tried a log-transformation but data becomes left-skewed.

In general, when data is distributed like this, what is the next best transformation to try if you want to normalize the data?

Comment: Please explain why you need to transform this dataset to look Normal.  (Such efforts are usually unnecessary.)

Comment: Computing the inverse of the normal CDF (cumulative distribution function) on the given data might give you close-to-normal distribution. The reason is that your distribution looks a little bit like a uniform distribution in [0,1]. In fact, if this were the case and if we call `u` a value measured in your distribution and set `x = F^-1(u)`, where `F(.)` is the standard normal CDF, we have: `Pr(X <= F^-1(u)) = Pr(F(X) <= u) = u = F(x)`, because `U` has been assumed to be uniform. In R you can get the inverse of the standard normal CDF of `u` by running `qnorm(u)`.

Comment: @mastropi thank you. makes total sense and it worked.

Comment: "Scaling" and "transforming to normality" are *completely different operations.*

Comment: @whuber maybe i did (or didn't) phrase this right, but for clustering isn't one of the ways to make variables comparable, which im lead to belive is a necessary step in clustering, to normalize numeric variables?

Comment: Where "normalize" is meant in the sense of "rescaling to a specified interval or other measure of variability," yes.  But not in the sense of "making the distribution approximately Normal."  That almost never is a requirement and often goes so far as to obscure or destroy useful information.